# LINQ Group By and Intersection between groups C#

Tags: c#, linq, intersect, group

I have the following **list** into C#:

```
table_schema | table_name | field_name | field_type
public         tableA       fieldA       character varying
public         tableA       fieldB       timestamp
public         tableA       fieldC       bytea
public         tableB       fieldA       character varying
public         tableB       fieldD       integer
other          tableC       fieldA       character varying
other          tableC       fieldE       integer
```

So   the field with name `fieldA` and type `character varying` exists to all.

The output should be a list object :

```
field_name | field_type
fieldA       character varying
```

Comment: LINQ to objects or LINQ to SQL? Is the *real* question how  to find the field+type that's common in all possible `schema.table` values? SQL's GROUP BY eliminates rows and can't be used to batch rows like this

Comment: The origin is coming from SQL some steps behind yes, but this result set exists into a list now. So I am focusing into pure lists. In addition I need to be sure that this field exists into all tables

Comment: You still have to explain what you really want to do. `Found in all tables` isn't the same as `found in most tables` or `the most frequent common column`. It's probably easier and faster to *not* use LINQ but pass through the list a single time to identify the common column(s). LINQ would have to scan the list multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest `GroupBy` and then `Aggregate` all these groups while `Intersect`ing their content:

```
var list = ...

var result = list
  .GroupBy(item => (item.table_schema, item.table_name),
           item => (item.field_name, item.field_type))
  .Select(group => group.AsEnumerable()) 
  .Aggregate((current, item) => current.Intersect(item))
  .ToList(); // <- Let's have a list of tuples
```

The only trick is line

```
   .Select(group => group.AsEnumerable())
```

We don't want to aggregate by `IGrouping<K, V>` but by more general `IEnumerable<V>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not think is working. I am getting more fields which are not common between all tables.

Comment: @Stavros Koureas: If you suspect that the code doesn't work, could you provide a *counter example* please? I `Intersect` `(field_name, field_type)` across *all* the schemas so, the result will be `(field_name, field_type)` which present in *all* schemas

Comment: @DimitryBychenko, the (field_name, field_type) should exists to all combinations of schemas and table_names not only schemas.

Comment: @Stavros Koureas: I see; in this case, let's group by pair : `(item => (item.table_schema, item.table_name)`; I've edited the answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same after your first post, its working now